Sharepoint List FieldValuesAsText in Powershell
I am writing PowerShell where I need to get the FieldValuesAsText of the List Item property. I am writing this in Server object model. I am not able to get the FieldValuesAsText. I am using sharepoint 2016.
Need help on this.
Thanks,
I tried in SOM
   $web = Get-SPWeb $SiteUrl

   $list =   $web.Lists["Library Name"]
  foreach($item in $list.Items)
  {
     // Not able to get the FieldValuesAsText from 
     $item.FieldValuesAsText
   }`

I tried in SOM but didn't get.Sorry I corrected it
